# Cannot test Cognito authenticated API Gateway call in Postman (its an ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH pool)

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I've managed to successfull login to the API gateway I've made via my iOS device and Cognito.  The problem is I'd like to use postman to test the API calls then implement them on the phone.  Currently, Postman cannot authenticate (despite AWS saying it can).  No matter what I do I get a 401 error (visible in the screen-shots)

What I've tried

**Downloaded the postman collection from AWS Api Gateway**
[image]

**Then imported it into postman, and switch the authentication to "AWS Signature"**
[image]

**And Here is a screen shot of the Postman Generated Header Info**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to call an API Gateway endpoint that is behind the built-in Cognito Authoriser.

I think you've misunderstood how you call an Cognito Authorised API Gateway:

1. Authorise against Cognito to get an `id_token`
2. Call API Gateway with the `Authorization` header set to `id_token`
3. Renew `id_token` every hour

By enabling `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` you're allowing the first step (sign-in to Cognito) to be simplified so that you can more easily do it manually. (If you hadn't, then you would need to do `SRP` calculations).

One way to get the `id_token` is to use the `aws cli` (further ways are shown in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-admin-authentication-flow)):

`aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id='[USER_POOL_ID]' --client-id='[CLIENT_ID]' --auth-flow=ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters="USERNAME=[USERNAME],PASSWORD=[PASSWORD]"`

You can then use the result (`AuthenticationResult.IdToken`) as the `Authorization` header in Postman (no need for the AWS v4 signature- that is only for IAM authentication).

n.b. a much fuller explanation with images [can be found here](https://hackernoon.com/full-guide-to-building-a-serverless-api-with-zero-code-c4f7871998f5).

Comment: makes sense but for some reason this does not work for me; I get an error like: not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I finally did to fix postman auth issues

1) Turned off `App Client Secret` in the Cognito pool.

2) Ran `aws --region us-east-1 cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --cli-input-json file://gettoken.json`

**JSON file example**

```
{
"UserPoolId": "us-east-1_**********", 
"ClientId": "******************", 
"AuthFlow": "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",

    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": "*********",
        "PASSWORD": "***********"
    }    
}
```

3) Went to **Postman > Authorization > Bearer** Copied the `idToken` value into the token field and everything worked.
[image]

NOTE: For those wondering if not using a secret client key is safe.  [See this article.](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/)